# I am trying to use PARSE deleteEventually with iOS SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

The Parse documentation clearly mentioned the PFObject Instance Method 'deleteEventually' but in SWIFT I get a compile error when trying to use it.

Comment: please post code and what error you are getting

Comment: /Users/hgg/Documents/apple/DEVELOPER/AppName/AppNameFramework/TableViewController.swift:231:9: 'UserClub' does not have a member named 'deleteEventually'

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it's a Swift module generation issue in Xcode.  Just import the Bolts header in your bridging header:

```
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

Comment: Once I create the Bridging-Header.h file I get the following 2 error:

/Users/hgg/Documents/apple/DEVELOPER/App/App-Bridging-Header.h:5:9: error: 'Bolts/Bolts.h' file not found

import

    ^
:0: error: failed to import bridging header '/Users/hgg/Documents/apple/DEVELOPER/App/App-Bridging-Header.h'

I have added the Parse.Framework and Bolts.Framework to the compiler SearchPaths/HeaderSearchPaths as I can see a single file called Parse and Bilts under each respective directory but these contain binary data.

Comment: Did you add the Parse and Bolts frameworks to your project?  It's not enough to add the search path, though I don't think you need the search path if the frameworks are part of your project.